# Sentence correction- Adverb

Tags: adverbs

> Despite knowing full well the negative consequences of our impatience, why many of us are impatient?

Should the word "full" be replaced by "fully"?

It's from a book. I am confused since I feel "well" should be modified by an adverb "fully" rather than an adjective "full".

Comment: I believe either is correct. Is this a sentence you've written or one you've found somewhere that confuses you?

Comment: If it's from a book, you should be sure to include the reference information. Have you come across the concept of a "[flat adverb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_adverb)"?

Comment: I wasn't aware till now. Thanks for the link. Will be mindful of mentioning the source information from next time.

Comment: The problem is with the word-order of the why-clause.  To "know full well" is idiomatic.

Comment: @user44702 Please add it to *this* question as well.

Comment: "Full was formerly used as an adverb in English. This has largely been replaced by fully, but "full well" remains in common usage, almost always modifying the verb "to know". It is sometimes corrected to "fully well", though this may seen as incorrect or a hypercorrection." https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/full_well

Answer (score 2):

The word "full" is also an adverb that means completely or entirely. So it can modify the other adverb well.  The phrase "to know full well" means to understand a situation completely.

Fully is also an adverb, but we use full as an adverb with well; it's a fixed phrase.

Comment: Downvote for getting the sentence structure wrong. Should be "why are many of us impatient?"

Comment: WhatRoughBeast, I don't mind your downvote. I replied to what the OP asked. He didn't ask to correct his sentence. Please see Catija's comments

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast That is not the subject of the sentence. Clearly you can't undo the vote now, but it's certainly not necessary to downvote an answer simply because it does not answer a question that was not asked.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence should read:

> Despite knowing full well the negative consequences of our impatience, why are (so) many of us <s>are</s> impatient?

In a question, the "are" changes its position. Also, the use of "so" in this kind of expression, while not necessary, is common and natural.

As for "know full well," it is true that

1 "full" is a 'flat adverb,' one that does not end in *-ly*,

but it is also true that

2 "know full well" is one of the most common collocations that uses this form. This can be seen by how many dictionaries give this expression as an example for "full" as an adverb. See the examples in [thefreedictonary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/full).

In my experience, *know full well* is more of a spoken expression, whereas "know fully well" is better for formal contexts, including much writing.

In your sentence, I would use "know fully well," because the flat-adverb version sounds dialectal, slangy, or just too informal for that sentence.

Comment: It's not the op's sentence and the question is not asking for it to be corrected.

Comment: Editing one's question without telling them what was fixed and why isn't helpful to the mistaken OP at all. @Cat was just indicating how ELLers usually help the OP with the other grammatical errors they have in their post, which aren't relevant to their main question. You're being outright rude. Please read a little about the policies instead of posting snarky comments next time.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M And how, sir or madam, do you know what is helpful to this OP? I could care less how ELLers do things. I am not an ELLer, I am here to help the OP, which I have done. And now my answer has been downvoted, despite the fact there is nothing wrong with it. Some "ELLer"  downvoted it just to be pissy.This is what makes SE an ugly and ultimately an ineffective place.

Comment: I dunno what is helpful to the OP, but editing their grammar without pointing out what was wrong with it or why isn't helpful. That should be obvious enough. Probably your previous rude comment had something to do with the downvote, but no one other than the downvoter can state the exact reason. Don't worry, if it's serial-voting, there are scripts that reverse it.

Comment: Even if your answer were correct, that wouldn't give you license to be rude.  Please [**Be Nice**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: Despite saying that you "dunno what is helpful to the OP," you go on to judge my answer based on--I guess--some other criteria. What other criteria than helpfulness to the user should there be? And it is not obvious to me that correcting a posted sentence without going into detail is not helpful to the OP. Perhaps, again, you could stymie yourself and let the learner make a comment as to what is helpful. As for a downvote of an answer because of a rude comment, well that makes a ton of sense. Not.

Comment: @snailboat My answer is correct. If not, per SE rules, change it to your liking. Your use of the subjunctive mood in your comment is rude.

Comment: Incorrect answers should just be downvoted, not edited. Other people can then add correct answers :)

Comment: @HarryCBurn you are apparently unaware of one of the main "features" of SE, as stated on its [welcome tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour): "Our goal is to have the best answers to every question, so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can edit them." Subtext: "Use edits to fix mistakes, improve formatting, or clarify the meaning of a post."

Comment: @User1 The purpose of an edit shouldn't be to completely change the meaning of a post, but to improve it in a way that isn't too significant. Otherwise, there would only be one answer for each post, and up/downvotes would be unnecessary. To add to list list, as it's just been brought to my intention: "clearly conflicts with the author's intent" is one of the reasons to reject an edit.

Comment: @User1 "fix mistakes" means to fix slight grammar, punctuation, capitalization or spelling errors. It does not mean to "correct an incorrect assertion in the answer".

Comment: @HarryCBurn  My post doesn't need a complete change in meaning. At least one SE native speaker user takes issue with my answer because it does not please _them_. This is done without any input from the OP as to whether they find anything "unhelpful about my answer. This is, of course, ridiculous. Anyway, perhaps the system you describe would be better. The voting system does not work.

Comment: Well, the system I describe is the one we use. I'm not saying that your answer needs an edit, but if it was edited in a bad way, then I totally agree that the system kinda' failed to do it's job.

Comment: I dunno, Harry et al. What I find ironic is that the answer by @Khan got a downvote, because it did not mention the grammar of the OP's sentence. My answer mentions this, in passing, and it gets a snarly comment.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn;t have downvoted. That being said, I'm not well versed on the topic. Perhaps it takes a keener eye than mine.